# Create, Drag drop and resize controls on runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, drag-and-drop, resize

I am trying to create a form which contains panels created programmaticaly and controls able to drag drop and resize just like Microsoft Visual Studio IDE.

And I created something like this. there should be so many lines (blue one) and also so many boxes(yellow one) and I can be able to move yellow boxes inside of blue lines. everything works with defined controls on design time.

[image]

and the source codes here

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool allowResize = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           

        panel1.AllowDrop = true;
        panel2.AllowDrop = true;
        panel3.AllowDrop = true; 
        panel4.AllowDrop = true;

        panel1.DragEnter += panel_DragEnter;
        panel2.DragEnter += panel_DragEnter;
        panel3.DragEnter += panel_DragEnter;
        panel4.DragEnter += panel_DragEnter;


        panel1.DragDrop += panel_DragDrop;
        panel2.DragDrop += panel_DragDrop;
        panel3.DragDrop += panel_DragDrop;
        panel4.DragDrop += panel_DragDrop;

        panelMove.MouseDown += panelMove_MouseDown;        

    }

    void panelMove_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        panelMove.DoDragDrop(panelMove, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    void panel_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    void panel_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Panel)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Panel))).Parent = (Panel)sender;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        allowResize = true;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        allowResize = false;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (allowResize)
        {
            this.panelMove.Height = pictureBox1.Top + e.Y;
            this.panelMove.Width = pictureBox1.Left + e.X;
        }
    }       
}
```

but I dont know how to create thoose controls (blue and yellow boxes ) on runtime.

Comment: Creating your own designer is never not a mistake.  VS makes it look too easy but it is a very substantial amount of work.  At least leverage the existing designer in your own program, check this [magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx)

Comment: May I suggest WPF instead? It' a lot more powerful and customizable. Take a look at [this Diagram Designer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1)

Comment: @ HighCore I have never tried, but it worth to try as it seems

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property of `Control`. Anchor allows the control to automatically re-sized at runtime.

> Use the Anchor property to define how a control is automatically
>   resized as its parent control is resized. Anchoring a control to its
>   parent control ensures that the anchored edges remain in the same
>   position relative to the edges of the parent control when the parent
>   control is resized.
>
> You can anchor a control to one or more edges of its container. For
>   example, if you have a Form with a Button whose Anchor property value
>   is set to Top and Bottom, the Button is stretched to maintain the
>   anchored distance to the top and bottom edges of the Form as the
>   Height of the Form is increased.

MSDN : [`Control.Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx)